# How to make gatsby-transformer-remark work with gatsby-plugin-i18n?

Tags: gatsby

When I configure the `pagesPaths` option of [`gatsby-plugin-i18n`](https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-i18n) the transformer [`gatsby-transformer-remark`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark) is never called.

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'example.com',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'content',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/content`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe',
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: 'margin-bottom: 1rem'
            }
          },
          'gatsby-remark-prismjs',
          'gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files',
          'gatsby-remark-smartypants',
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1140,
              quality: 90,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-i18n',
      options: {
        langKeyDefault: 'en',
        useLangKeyLayout: false,
        prefixDefault: false
        pagesPaths: ['/src/pages/', '/src/content/']
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I have `/src/content/` in my `pagesPaths` the markdown files in this folder are never processed by remark, hence I can never add custom node fields to this nodes. There are just no nodes with the internal type `MarkdownRemark`:

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  switch (node.internal.type) {
    case 'MarkdownRemark': {
      const { permalink, layout } = node.frontmatter
      const { relativePath } = getNode(node.parent)

      let slug = permalink

      if (!slug) {
        slug = `/${relativePath.replace('.md', '')}/`
      }

      // Used to generate URL to view this content.
      createNodeField({
        node,
        name: 'slug',
        value: slug || ''
      })

      // Used to determine a page layout.
      createNodeField({
        node,
        name: 'layout',
        value: layout || ''
      })
      break
    }
    default: {
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Does someone have an idea what's happening here?

I'm using Gatsby `2.18.17`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I seem to be running into a similar issue.

Comment: Well, eventually I wrote my own plugin: https://github.com/openscript/gatsby-starter-dogmatism/tree/master/plugins/gatsby-plugin-i18n-l10n

Comment: That's one way to solve the problem.